# How to convert a markdown file into a csv file keeping the tree structure

Tags: python, r, markdown

I have a `md` file similar to:

```
# level_1
## level_11
- ind1
- ind2
## level_12
- ind3
# level_2
## level_21
- ind4
```

and I want to convert it in a `csv` file similar to this (preferably using R or Python):

```
level1, level_11, ind1
level1, level_11, ind2
level1, level_12, ind3
level2, level_21, ind4
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is a reasonable example of desired input and output, but what have you tried so far ... ? If you can show us some strategy you've tried and where you've gotten stuck someone will try to help you ... (Looping through the lines one at a time, checking the number of `#` characters at the beginning, updating the level-1 and level-2 headings, and then printing an appropriate CSV line, seems like a fairly easy strategy)

Comment: I didn't try any solution yet. I thought I could find a converter similar to `pandoc` for this purpose.

Comment: It would be easy to write a small python script that does what you desire. The steps are: read in file, convert file to data structure, dump data structure to CSV. Recursion would probably be your friend here while crawling the markdown file.

Comment: I don't think recursion is even necessary. `initialize level1=level2 to ""; for L in file: if one #, update level 1; if two ##, update level 2; otherwise print current level1, level2, value; end` is the pseudocode

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

def parse_markdown(file_path):
  """
  Parses a markdown file and returns a list of rows for a CSV file.
  """
  rows = []
  current_level1 = None
  current_level2 = None
  with open(file_path, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
      line = line.strip()
      # Check for level 1 heading
      if line.startswith("# "):
        current_level1 = line[2:]
        current_level2 = None
      # Check for level 2 heading
      elif line.startswith("## "):
        current_level2 = line[3:]
      # Check for list item
      elif line.startswith("- "):
        if current_level1 and current_level2:
          rows.append([current_level1, current_level2, line[2:]])
        elif current_level1:
          rows.append([current_level1, None, line[2:]])
  return rows

def write_csv(file_path, rows):
  """
  Writes a list of rows to a CSV file.
  """
  with open(file_path, "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["level1", "level_11", "ind"])
    writer.writerows(rows)

# Example usage
rows = parse_markdown("your_markdown_file.md")
write_csv("output_csv_file.csv", rows)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.